# Firefox opening images as downloads

Tags: firefox

Firefox used to show images in a new tab when I navigate to a URL like: http://example.com/images/photo.jpg, but now it just shows me a download box instead.

How do I revert back to showing images in a tab?

Comment: Could it be a plugin or add-on? Check Tools -> Addons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most of the time due to a bad Content-Type filled by the HTTP server. I guess it doesn't happen while visiting [this site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crnmt.jpg) for example. Check the server configuration if you are able to.

Comment: Sadly this is the case. Looking into it in a bit more detail, it's only some sites that cause this. :(

Comment: You could check the "Applications" tab in the "Options" menu of Firefox. Under that search for JPEG and see the action, change it appropriately, if needed..